# Sleep button no longer works

Tags: keyboard, sleep

I need the sleep button on my keyboard (aptly labelled Zzz) to put the laptop to sleep, but pressing it no longer does anything. I'm pretty sure it used to work.
Output from xev:

```
FocusIn event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyPointer

KeymapNotify event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   64  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer
```

I'm not sure what this means and how to go about debugging it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and copy and run gconf-editor and go to 'apps -> gnome-power-manager' and check 'can_hibernate' and 'can_suspend'.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have these keys, so I added them, but that didn't help. Anyway the computer is perfectly able to hibernate - it just doesn't respond to the button.